Azure Pipeline test results - links to source code in stack trace
In the past in Azure Pipelines I've run tests from within the pipeline (YAML) and for the tests that fail, the Azure DevOps UI has links back to the source code that were automatically added in the test results stack trace.
The previous success was done in .net with SpecFlow tests. The test results were in .trx file format.
The current problem is that I cannot get the links to the source code to happen. The current project is java, using testng, outputting to junit.
In both cases the tests are published using PublishTestResultsV2 pipeline task.
In what cases do the links to the source code get added? I have searched all over the documentation and the Azure Pipelines -related source code and found no answer. Is this something that is specific to .trx/vstest target?

"In what cases do the links to the source code get added?" - the
Results format mapping
and the Attachments support
is probably what you're looking for.
